# When entering an integer it keeps executing the else statement, trying to search user's input by isdigit if its a number, don't understand why

Tags: c

```
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> 

int main(void)
{
    double InputNum; //needs to be double for test cases
    int NumLoops = 11; // loops runs 11 times 
    printf("Enter number please: ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &InputNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < InputNum; --NumLoops) //incrementally goes down 
    {
        if (isdigit(InputNum))
        {
            printf("%lf\n", InputNum+1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Must be a number!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

> program incrementally increases by one starting at user's input, this happens 11 times and than ends program, unfortunately it does not do that and keeps printing out the else statement in this code, Any suggestions?

Comment: The shown code doesn't make any sense. What is the logic behind: 1) Inputing a `double` value "`InputNum`", 2) Initializing `i`, an `int` value to 0; 3) The `for` loop comparing `i` to `InputNum`, but there's nothing, whatsoever, that will ever update or increment `i`, but the loop decrements some other variable `NumLoop` when the `for` loop iterates,for some odd reason; 4) Using `isdigit`, which is for `char` values, with that `double` value, instead. Sounds like you need [an emergency meeting with your rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: I think you're not understanding how `scanf_s()` works. In brief, it will scan only input that matches the pattern specified, and stop at the first character that doesn't match. It will return the number of values successfully matched and read into its parameters. In this case, you specified "%lf", so it will accept a sign, digits, and decimal, but if the user types space, "a", "!", etc. it will not read that input and return (e.g. "1.1" will return 1 with `InputNum` as 1.1, "1.1.1" will do the same, "1a" will return 1 with `InputNum` as 1.0, "abc" will return 0 with `InputNum` unchanged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that `scanf()` is converting the integer you enter to a double. So when you type an int for example 5, will be converted to 5.00000, and `isdigit()` will not convert this to a digit so it always fails.

This is how I would do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(void)
{
    double InputNum;   //needs to be double for test cases
    int NumLoops = 11; // loops runs 11 times 
    
    printf("Enter number please: ");
    scanf("%lf", &InputNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < NumLoops; ++i) 
    {
        if ((InputNum - floor(InputNum)) == 0)  
        {
            printf("%f\n", InputNum+1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Must be a number!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```int NumCheck (double *ch)
{
    double num = *ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < *ch; i++)
    {
        if (i < 'a' || 'z' > i)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return num;
}``` // @ImNotGoodAtDis I appreciate your example and I have refactored some of my code. I still don't understand why my function here is not working. What I am trying to do is see if the user's input contains any alpha characters and if it does then I would like to exit the program or print "invalid".

Comment: You can't iterate through a double like that. A double is not a string.

Comment: What I suggest doing is reading the user input as a string and then converting each byte to an ASCII int and checking for alphabetic characters.